# Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory (Public Preview)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

From above link, I saw content below:

> After hearing from customers during the preview, we're planning to replace this functionality with a new feature in Azure Active Directory Conditional Access. Once the new feature is complete, this functionality will eventually be deprecated after a notification period. If you use the Configurable Token Lifetime policy, be prepared to switch to the new Conditional Access feature once it's available.

My questions are:

1. Whether Conditional Access feature is completed and released?
2. How to configure token life time using Azure Active Directory Conditional Access?
3. To enable Azure Active Directory Conditional Access, AD Premium license is must?
4. Cannot we use AD Premium Trial version with out O365 Subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you could not configure token lifetime using Azure Active Directory Conditional Access for now. And later the Conditional Access feature is completed and released, I will update your questions.

Comment: But while users read this answer in future. please check yourself the feature is released or not.